# Shell Vs Process.start for executing external application

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows, shell, process

I can open the windows calculator from my application in following ways:

- Using `Shell()`

  ```
  Shell("C:\WINDOWS\system32\calc.exe")
  ```
- Using `Process.start()`

  ```
  Process.start("C:\WINDOWS\system32\calc.exe")
  ```
- Open notepad application

  ```
  Shell("C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe", AppWinStyle.NormalFocus)  
  Process.start("C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe", AppWinStyle.NormalFocus)
  ```

Can anyone tell me that what is the difference between these two calls? which one is the best practice?

Comment: @   Erti-Chris Eelmaa : shell() is a built in function used to Run an executable program and returns an integer containing the program's process ID if it is still running.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the two examples there is essentially no difference but

`Process.Start` is preferred because it gives you more options on controlling the process. You can specify much more options using a [ProcessStartInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb(v=vs.110).aspx) object as a parameter.

`Shell` only returns the process id which you would have to look up in the list of running processes whereas `Process.Start` return a `Process` object which you can use to check for its state etc.

Also note that `Shell` resides in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace which *largely* contains deprecated methods for legacy purposes. You should try to avoid using anything in here in favour of an alternative in another namespace.